# Java package - class not found, same directory

Tags: java

I have two Java classes "giveMyOb" and "dataConn" declared in the same directory. Both are public classes. "giveMyOb" has a static method "getMine()". Inside dataConn, I called the static method as

```
giveMyOb.getMine();
```

When I try to compile dataConn.java, the following error is returned.

"Cannot find symbol

symbol: variable giveMyOb
location : class dataConn
                giveMyOb.getMine();  "

It used to work earlier. But is not working now. Why is that?

Additional Information: JDK 1.6. Windows 7. 64 bit.

Update(30 days after the question): When compiled from Eclipse, the classes are referenced and it works. But the same won't work when compiling from command line. I was unable to figure out the reason and nothing logical comes to my mind!

Comment: Can you provide the `giveMyOb` class code?

Comment: Try to recompile the class giveMyOb.java first

Comment: giveMyOb.java (now GiveMyOb.java) compiles without any error. All this was working a few months ago. I just can't figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
javac -classpath . *.java
```

ought to create both .class files at the same time.  It's more complicated by packages.  I'm assuming you have none.

Learn the Sun Java coding conventions.  You aren't following them with those class names.  They should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Both the classes do not belong to any packages.  I changed the first letters of both classes to capitals(all file name, class name, constructor, and references in the other class) and still face the same error

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using small letters for almost all the classes I have written till date!!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

giveMyOb.java

```
public class giveMyOb {
    public static String getMine() {
        return "Yay, it works!";
    }
}
```

dataConn.java

```
public class dataConn {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(giveMyOb.getMine());
    }
}
```

Then compile it all:

```
javac *.java
```

and run the main class:

```
java -cp . dataConn
// output: Yay, it works!
```

Note that [Java's coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) recommend class names start with a capital.

If "it" still doesn't work, try removing the `.class` files manually then recompile again.

Comment: +1 *"Note that Java's coding conventions recommend class names start with a capital."* And even if you disagree with some of the recommendations (and some of them definitely stray into style), you really, really should conform to *that* one.

Comment: GiveMyOb.java compiles sucessfully, but DataConn.java throws the same error faced earlier. Thanks for the shorter example. Does this work in your environment??

Comment: you should also capitalize the static call to getMine() : GiveMyOb.getMine()

Comment: @Jeroen, only if the class is called `GiveMyOb`, which it isn't in my example.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I just thought Sandeep might have forgotten to capitalize it after capitalizing the class names.

Comment: @Jeroen I capitalized it when I tried again. It still doesn't work. I capitalized all the Filenames, Class Names, Constructors and at the place where GiveMyOb.getMine() is called. I just discovered that this is happening to all my previously working programs. Have to be some problem with my PC settings. Can I change the original question to reflect my current problem(i.e, capitalize the class name by editing my question)??

Comment: The capitalization doesn't matter: it is just a convention. It seems that your problem is not programming related however, but there's something wrong with the installation of your JDK. I'd suggest reinstalling the JDK and if that fails, post in a forum dedicated to OS/application questions instead (http://superuser.com, for example).

Comment: Thanks Bart. I will do that. I am booting to Ubuntu for my programming at home, but at work I should solve this!